# Issues building Docker images with GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

So, I have been trying to move to GitHub Actions for CI/CD. While I was writing a workflow, I faced some issues in building the image. The error is "Process completed with exit code 1". And I am unable to figure out what's wrong with my file. I mean, I got most of it from docs.

The step which is causing the error is "build" - docker build -t gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/github-action-test:latest.

```
name: cloud-run-deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Cloud Run Deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup GCP Service Account
        uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          version: "latest"
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - name: Configure Docker
        run: |
          gcloud auth configure-docker
      - name: Build
        run: |
          docker build -t gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/github-action-test:latest .
      - name: Push
        run: |
          docker push gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/github-action-test:latest
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          gcloud run deploy github-action-test \
          --region europe-west1 \
          --image gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/github-action-test \
          --platform managed \
          --allow-unauthenticated \
          --project ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
```

Comment: Does this error happen with any docker command? If I'm not mistaken, Docker isn't installed on ubuntu-latest, and your action might not recognize docker commands directly.

Comment: My configure seems to be working.... So, I doubt that docker is missing

Comment: `Exit code 1` can be an error in the file name or an application error. Make sure you are in the directory of the docker file or you can also try `gcloud builds` instead.

Comment: Slr, guys.....was dealing with something. Here, it seems like my file is not reading my Github Secrets which I verified are there. I am not sure what I am missing but it's something very fundamental I believe.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? My image is successfully uploaded to the cloud but github report the Error...